# show and empty paragraphs click jquery

Tags: jquery, replace

Here is my problem : 
 I use http://jqvmap.com/
I try to show a paragraph with the id "deleg" when you click on a country **and when you click on another country, this one replace the other**.

Later I want to show a picture of the delegation received.

Code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_en',
        backgroundColor: '#a5bfdd',
        borderOpacity: 0.75,
         borderWidth: 1,
        color: '#f4f3f0',
        hoverOpacity: 0.7,
         hoverColor: '#c9dfaf',
        selectedColor: '#666666',
        enableZoom: true,
        showTooltip: true,
        values: sample_data,
        selectedColor: '#c9dfaf',
        selectedRegion: null,
        showTooltip: true,
        scaleColors: ['#FFA953', '#D94600'],
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
        onRegionClick: function(element, code, region)
    {
        var message = 'Réception délégation :  "'
            + region+'"';


       if($('#deleg').html().trim()){
        $('#deleg').append(message);
       } else {
        $('#deleg').empty();
       }
        /*if(($("#deleg").html().trim())){
              $("#deleg").append(message);
        } else{
            console.log("test");
        }*/
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: $.trim($("#deleg").html())

Comment: didn't get where the problem is? Please be more specific..